# Problem compiling a vhdl file

Tags: compiling

I have ha.vhdl and ha_tb.vhdl files in one of my directory and I made a 
 makefile in which the commands goes this way

```
ha: ha.vhdl ha_tb.vhdl
    ghdl -a $(GHDL_ARGS) $^
    ghdl -e $(GHDL_ARGS) $@

clean:
    rm *.o *.cf
```

As I run **ghdl -s** command for ha.vhdl and ha_tb.vhdl it shows 
show no compilation errors.

After running the make command 
it goes in terminal this way:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ghdl: compilation error
```

Can anyone please point out what am I missing ?
Or someone say if there is any alternative?
        Thnx in advance !!!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ghdl`, however I can't imagine `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz` meaning anything other than that you need to install the `zlib1g-dev` development package

Comment: Hey thanks a lot .It works after installing that package .btw how did you point it precisely?